# Basic trig angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If you had the the following,  the following is working in radians

$$sin^{-1}(.5)=.52$$

Then we know our angle could either be in the first quadrant or the second quadrant

In the first quadrant it would just be .52, then for the second quadrant it would be $\pi-0.52$

But what if I wanted to find it in the 3rd of 4th quadrant

For the third would it be $\pi+.52$ or ${3\pi\over2}-
0.52$ and then for the 4th quadrant would it be $2\pi-0.52$ or ${3\pi\over2}+0.52$?

Comment: Just a side comment, but $\,\arcsin(.5)=\pi/6 \simeq 0.52359877\dots \ne 0.52\,$. `Then we know our angle could either be in the first quadrant or the second quadrant ` That's correct. `But what if I wanted to find it in the 3rd of 4th quadrant` It's not there, as you just wrote before.

Comment: "Then we know our angle could either be in the first quadrant or the second quadrant "  What angle?  The angle given is .52.  There's nothing to figure out.  There is just a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0 \le \theta < \frac {\pi}2$ is in the first quadrant with $\sin \theta = y; \cos \theta = x;$ and $0 \le x,y \le 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Then the corresponding angle in the second quadrant is $\pi - \theta$ and $\sin(\pi - \theta) = y$ and $\cos (\pi - \theta) = -x$.

The corresponding angle in the third quadrant is $\pi + \theta$ which can also be written as $-(\pi - \theta) = -\pi + \theta$.  $\sin (\pi + \theta) = -y$ and $\cos(\pi + \theta) = -x$.

The corresponding angle in the fourth quadrant is $2\pi - \theta$ which can also be written as $- \theta$.  $\sin (-\theta)= -y$ and $\cos(-\theta) = x$.

And that's it.  That is the relationship between *EVERY* angle in *ANY* quadrant to any other.  And that is why tables and arc sines and cosines often only deal with the first (and maybe the second of the fourth) quadrant.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\theta=\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

We have two possibilities of the angle that is

In the first quadrant we have

$$\theta_1=\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi$$ for every cycle.

In the second quadrant, we apply $\theta_2=\pi-\theta_1$

Which yields

$$\theta_2=\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}$$

$$\theta_2=\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi$$

For every cycle.

k takes the values of integers.

You claim that you want to find positive sin the the third and fourth quadrant which is untrue.

[image]

Take this example, $\sin\theta=-\frac{1}{2}$. We know that sin is negative in Third and fourth quadrant.

$$\sin\theta=-\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\sin^{-1}-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{\pi}{6}$$

We know that $-\frac{\pi}{6}$ is measured from the clockwise direction. So, by $2\pi+(-\frac{\pi}{6})=\frac{11\pi}{6}$. We thus get the angle measured from the counter clockwise direction.

That will be the first angle which is inside the fourth quadrant.

Simply by

$$\frac{\pi}{6}+\pi=\frac{7\pi}{6}$$

We get the third angle. What I did is just using symmetry.

[image]

Comment: I am wondering the relationship for the 3rd and 4th quadrants, not particularly this exact example but I understand how to find it in the first and second but what if I had some value I wanted to find for negative sin so in the 3rd and 4th quadrant  say if I took the inverse of some value of sin and got a negative value it could either be in the 3rd or 4th

Comment: The relations are straightforward. (You should have learned them in the second week). For $0 \le \theta \le \frac {\pi }2$ (in the first quadrant) with $\sin \theta = y; 0 \le y \le 1$.  Then $\sin(\pi - \theta) = y$ (in the second) and $\sin (\pm \pi + \theta) = -y$ (in the third quadrant) and $\sin(2\pi - \theta) = \sin(-\theta) = -y$ (in the fourth quadrant).  Meanwhile if $\cos(\theta) = x$ then $\cos(\pi - \theta)=-x;\cos(\pi + \theta)=-x;\cos(-\theta) =x$.

Answer (score 0):

### Hint

[image: Trig Angles]

**Only the trig angle which is written in the quadrant is positive, all others are negative. Does that answer your question?**